# Running part of the method at the same time in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a method and I want to run only the parts of the method at the same time. For example, I want to run doSomethingOne, doSomethingTwo and doSomethingThree methods at the same time, but they should start after the start variable and end before the end variable.

```
public static void someMethod() {
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    
    pool.execute(() -> {
        doSomethingOne;
    });
    pool.execute(() -> {
        doSomethingTwo;
    });
    pool.execute(() -> {
        doSomethingThree;
    });
    
    pool.shutdown();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 1_000_000_000L);
}
```

Comment: Does this help you https://www.baeldung.com/java-stop-execution-after-certain-time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Wait for tasks to complete

Your current code will already let all three threads start after `start` is initialized. However, the `shutdown` method doesn't wait for all the work to be done.

### `CountDownLatch`

You can use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) to wait until all jobs are done:

```
public static void someMethod() {
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
    final CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    pool.execute(() -> {
        try {
            doSomethingOne;
        } finally {
            endLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    pool.execute(() -> {
        try {
            doSomethingTwo;
        } finally {
            endLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    pool.execute(() -> {
        try {
            doSomethingThree;
        } finally {
            endLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    
    pool.shutdown();

    // exception handling omitted
    endLatch.await();

    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println((end - start) / 1_000_000_000L);
}
```

There are two things that can mess with timing: the time it takes to schedule the tasks, and the time it takes to shutdown the pool. Another `CountDownLatch` can help with the first, and reordering the `shutdown` call with the other:

```
public static void someMethod() {
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

    try {
        final CountDownLatch startLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        final CountDownLatch endLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        pool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                startLatch.await(); // exception handling omitted
                doSomethingOne;
            } finally {
                endLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
        pool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                startLatch.await(); // exception handling omitted
                doSomethingTwo;
            } finally {
                endLatch.countDown();
            }
        });
        pool.execute(() -> {
            try {
                startLatch.await(); // exception handling omitted
                doSomethingThree;
            } finally {
                endLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        startLatch.countDown();
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        // exception handling omitted
        endLatch.await();

        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println((end - start) / 1_000_000_000L);
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The start latch acts like a GO signal - everything can prepare itself as necessary, but only actually start when the GO is given.

Of course, with 3 almost identical blocks of code, you'd create a utility method for that, which only takes the `doSomethingOne` part.